# Google Maps - get values from location array based on the map's current viewpoint

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Edit: 
**Question** = "is there a way to loop through the array and check if each location (long/lat) falls within the current viewport directly" (failing that get all markers within the viewport)

**Background**:

I have an array of locations (lat, long, id).

I want to:

- On a Google Map, use the location array to display markers.
- The user can scroll/zoom the map.
- Have a button underneath the map, so when the user has decided on an area, he can click the button, and the code will **return the ids (from the location array) that are contained within the viewport / map bounds**.

There is a .contains for Google, so I guess you could potentially use that with something like

`map.getBounds().contains` and somehow reference each marker.getPosition()

but I wonder if there's a way to loop through the array and check if each location (long/lat) falls within the current viewport directly

Comment: What is your exact question? Do you expect to receive an answer on a list of the points you presented, or your question is: if there's a way to loop through the array and check if each location (long/lat) falls within the current viewport directly

Comment: yes, ideally if I could check all locations in an array, and return the ones that fall within the current viewport

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this (not tested), map is the google.maps.Map object and needs to be in scope. markersArray is the array of markers.

```
for (var i=0; i< markersArray.length; i++) {
   if (map.getBounds().contains(markersArray[i].getPosition())) {
      // the marker is in view
   } else {
      // the marker is not in view
   } 
}
```

Comment: thanks geocodezip. i think you missed a closing ')' but I am going to try this out in a bit - as you said I probably need to make an of the markers.

Comment: fixed the missing ")".  Still not tested.

Comment: You can use your existing array, but if you want to do something to the marker if it is in view, you will need a reference to it.  If all you need is the id, you can get that by processing through your existing array, you just need to make a google.maps.LatLng for each entry to test in the if statement in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/UA2g2/1/

Thanks geocodezip, you gave me the idea on how to solve it via looping through the array. I don't know if this is the most efficient way, but I put together some code that seems to do what I want - if you check the jsfiddle above and view console you can see that it logs when and which points are in the viewport.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var myOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51, -2),
  zoom: 9,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  var storeArray = new Array(["51.38254", "-2.362804", "ID1"], ["51.235249", "-2.297804","ID2"], ["51.086126", "-2.910767","ID3"]);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {

      for (i = 0; i < storeArray.length; i++) {  
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(storeArray[i][0], storeArray[i][1]),
            map: map
         });
      }

      for (var i=0; i<storeArray.length; i++) {
          if (map.getBounds().contains(new google.maps.LatLng(storeArray[i][0], storeArray[i][1]))) {
              console.log("marker: " + storeArray[i][2]);
            }
        } 

  });


});
```